# Makefile patsubst multiple occcurence in replacement pattern

Tags: makefile

I have 3 dirs and want to link an executable against the libraries

I already have the directory list:

`DIRS=Math Graph Test`

I want to get the library list like this:

`LIBS=Math/libMath.a Graph/libGraph.a Test/libTest.a`

If I use this:

`$(DIRS:%=%/%.a)`

I get:

`Math/%.a Graph/%.a Test/%.a`

[GNU Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) says:

> Only the first ‘%’ in the pattern and replacement is treated this way; **any subsequent ‘%’ is unchanged**.

Here I need 2 occurrences to be replaced, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eventually I used:

LIBS := `$(join $(DIRS), $(DIRS:%=/lib%.a))`

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to use a loop:

```
LIBS := $(foreach D,$(DIRS),$D/lib$D.a)
```